# AWS Lambda access port for spawned process

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

With AWS Lambda I get errors accessing a spawned process on a port.

So I'm spawning a process with;

```
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn
```

which starts a process running on a particular port;

```
spawn(path.resolve(__dirname, 'chrome/headless_shell'), ['--no-sandbox', `--remote-debugging-port=${CHROME_PORT}`])
```

I'm using PORT 3006. AWS Lambda throws the following error:

> Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3006

Hopefully there is some configuration I can change with AWS, or some safe port range I can use?

Context: I'm generating PDF's with chrome headless - this works outside of lambda. Yay.

Comment: Spawing child process on where? I don't think Lambda allows you to interact the machine internals where it is running (except the /tmp storage). You might need to consider re-architect this.

Comment: You can't do that with AWS Lambda.